# iphone listview with several cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have been able to make the listview show a single field of data using parts of the code like below.

```
NSMutableArray *array;
..
..
  array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [array addObject:@"John Doe"];
```

However I want to keep several fields, like:
 Name
 ID
 Date of Birth

I assume the NSMutableArrary is a NSString but I need something like a struct in C that holds the fields I need.

The ID would be "Hidden" but I need to access it when the user clicks on the line.  How I access the ID and the other fields?  How do I set this up so the list has the information?

Does anyone have any example code that might explain how to do this?

**EDIT #1**: Thanks for the comments, but I am too new to iPhone and really need to find example code on how to do this. While the comments make it sound like can do this, I dont know where to start.  Can someone post example code for the idea of 3 fields?

**EDIT #2**: I have tried everything so far, is the the correct way to do this or should I use the ideas below?

`Userrec.m`

```
#import "UserRec.h"
@implementation Userrec
@synthesize Name, ID;
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n ID:(NSString *)d {
    self.Name = n;
    self.ID = d;
    return self;
}
@end
```

`UserRec.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface Userrec : NSObject {
NSString *Name;
NSString *ID;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *ID;
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n ID:(NSString *)d;
@end
```

`UserList.m`

```
@synthesize userrecs;
…
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *Name = @"Name";
    NSString *ID = @"IID";
    Userrec *userrec = [[Userrec alloc] initWithName:Name ID:ID ];
    [userrecs addObject:userrec];
    NSLog(@"Count %d",[userrecs count]);
    [userrec release];
    NSLog(@"Count %d",[userrecs count]);
}
```

After I addobject and check the count its = 0. So I assume something is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at an [NSMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  it seems like the exact thing you would want to use

Edit:
Here's some sample code

```
NSMutableArray *myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *myRow = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[myRow setObject:@"John Doe" forKey:@"Name"];
[myRow setObject:@"4738" forKey:@"ID"];
[myRow setObject:@"1/23/45" forKey:@"DOB"];
[myData addObject:myRow];
[myRow release];
//Repeat from dictioanry alloc through release for each row you need to add
```

To display this in a UITableView, you need to have a UITableViewController class.  In there override the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function.  here is a simple implementation of that function

```
-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    static NSString *kCellID = @"cellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReuseableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
    if ( cell == nil )
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellID] autorelease];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary curRow = [myData objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [curRow objectForKey:@"Name"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: how would I use this with a listview? It doesnt seem to directly correlate to the existing mutablearray

Comment: MutableArray just holds generic NSObjects, so you have an array of dictionaries.  The dictionaries hold the key,value pairs you're looking for.

Comment: how then do I make it show up on the listview?  See extra notes above

Comment: I added the new tangent above that I am trying to make this work with. I am going to try your suggestion here now..  thanks again

Comment: With your second edit, you are releasing the array before calling count, that is why its showing 0, do not release it if you intend to hold onto that data

Comment: @Dan F I sure do appreciate the help.  I am trying to make the code you have here work, but it errors on the first line with "Invalid Modifier".  Was this supposed to work verbtim?

Comment: Getting an error on `NSInteger row = [indexPath row];`? I haven't tested it or compiled it, but it is almost exactly what I have in an existing project

Comment: The release was after but I removed the release and still is blank

Comment: This errors: NSMutableArray myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: Oh, I missed the *'s, that should be `NSMutableArray *myData` and `NSMutableDictionary *myRow` edited the code to reflect that

Comment: I guess I need to make the myData global to the class?

Comment: I had to tweak a little bit of the 2nd method for the cell but it IS WORKING! The way you showed me seems easier than setting up a class like what I started with.  Would you do it this way for all of the list views you need? Once again thank you! If you were close by I would buy you dinner!

Answer (score 1):

NSMutableDictionary is the best way to go. You can do something as follows:

`NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"John Doe", @"Name", [NSNumber numberWithInt:5], @"ID", nil];`

You can keep adding as many fields as you like with that same template, even NSArray objects. I'd look up the documentation if you have any more trouble. Remember, you can only store pointers to objects in an NSDictionary. Things like

`NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"John Doe", @"Name", 5, @"ID", nil];`

won't work. Good Luck!